# How to setup Nitro with Texniccenter

Tags: latex

Kindly tell me how to setup texniccenter with nitro as i haven't find any helpful material on google

I am also using sumatra and it is working fine but nitro isn't working with it
and just result in a message

"cannot exeecute the command"

i want specific answer to it how to setup texniccenter and nitro together to work successfully  and what will be the name of the server in case of using nitro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its khalid mahmood here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Well no one replied and at last i got the solution specific for nitro usage with texniccenter

with the help of the very last post on the following link

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=17164

and i can also post image of my conf if u wish, once i get accross 10 reputation restriction imposed by stackoverflow to post images